# How to set every value in column 0 in tensor to 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

I have zero experience in tensorflow or python, and the syntax is not really that well described in the API-reference.

What i want to do is set the zeroth-column to 1 for the tensor to perform Multiple linear regression.

This is what i've got so far:

```
def MLR(M, N):
    X = tf.random.uniform([M,N])
    y = tf.random.uniform([M])
    bias = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[M])
    X = tf.concat([bias, X],axis=0)
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(X)
    print(X)
    #w = np.dot( np.dot( np.linalg.matrix_power( (np.dot(Xt, X)) ,(-1)) ,Xt), y)
    return
```

But i only get incomprehensible errors when i run this. And no matter what i try and change it does not work.
Error:

```
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1 and 9. Shapes are [1] and [9]. for 'concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [100,1], [100,9], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <0>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like `bias = tf.ones([M, 1], tf.int32)`. 
The error is telling you the shapes are not compatible:

`Shapes are [1] and [9]. for 'concat'`
You need to concat vectors/tensors with matching lenghts at axis,
you either need to concatenate them with `axis=1` or change the first dimension.

Comment: This sadly did not change anything, added the error message for better understanding

Comment: It works now, could you explain why that changes it? What das the axes here stand for?

Comment: It's indicating the dimension on where to concatenate the tensors, meaning row or column wise when dealing with 2-D objects